# Terminal Find Specific File

Tags: python, macos, terminal, executable

NOTE: This is for MacOSX

I am working on a launcher for an app and the only way I can make terminal find the file is putting the direct root.
If I can get around this so it would work in any location what would the code be?
Here is the code in the executable:

```
#!/bin/bash  
python /Users/imac/Desktop/Notepad+/Contents/main.py
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I'll try to be more specific.

Comment: Since you can't run a python script as an app I have to make an executable or shell script to run the command `python /Users/imac/Desktop/Notepad+/Contents/main.py` . But If I go on another computer it is not the same directory. Is there a way terminal can always find the same file. I tried /main.py which means in the same folder but it still can't find the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path always will change from computer to computer. You can run executable in the same directory with

```
python main.py
```

for python 3

```
python3 main.py
```

Your shell script will be like.

```
#!/bin/bash  
python main.py
```

I hope it will help

Comment: Thanks I will try this script

Comment: After trying this script it came up with an error. Below I will list the error:

Comment: Last login: Fri Jan  6 08:30:00 on ttys001
Griffins-iMac:~ imac$ /Volumes/PadNote\ Installer/PadNote/PadNote ; exit;
python: can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

Comment: This command should work if your shell script and python script are in the same directory.

Comment: Do you add python to the path. If it is actually user can execute your script by clicking your main.py file.

Comment: do you have an email I can send a pic to

Comment: harunergul@outlook.com